# How to use transformations in pair-wise RDD in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to transform this RDD:

```
[(['1', '2', '3'], 'abc'), (['4', '5', '6'], 'xyz')]
```

to this form:

```
[('1', 'abc'), ('2', 'abc'), ('3', 'abc'), ('4', 'xyz'), ('5', 'xyz'), ('6', 'xyz')]
```

How can I achieve it with RDD transformations in PySpark?

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't have 50rep to comment on Rakesh's solution, I'm gonna post my own answer, which is pretty similar to Rakesh's, except that we don't need to call `map` before `flatMap`, just use `flatMap` directly. As its name suggested, `flatMap` flatten the result, calling `map` prior to that is unnecessary.

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([(['1', '2', '3'], 'abc'), (['4', '5', '6'], 'xyz')])
r = rdd.flatMap(lambda item: [(k, item[1]) for k in item[0]])
r.collect() # to show result
```

Comment: Initially, I tried the same thing. Somehow missed something and didn't work for me. Now tried your answer and it worked well. Thanks for a great answer. Upvoted

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `flatMap` function, also need to do some comprehension for this. Here are steps to do this -

**Create rdd with provided data -**

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([(['1', '2', '3'], 'abc'), (['4', '5', '6'], 'xyz')])
rdd.collect()
[(['1', '2', '3'], 'abc'),
(['4', '5', '6'], 'xyz')]
```

**Map each sub keys wit values to form `key,value` pair -**

```
rdd.map(lambda x:[(i,x[1]) for i in x[0]],).collect()
[[('1', 'abc'), ('2', 'abc'), ('3', 'abc')],
 [('4', 'xyz'), ('5', 'xyz'), ('6', 'xyz')]]
```

**Finally, apply flatMap to break this into the number of rows -**

```
rdd.map(lambda x:[(i,x[1]) for i in x[0]],).flatMap(lambda x:x).collect()
[('1', 'abc'),
 ('2', 'abc'),
 ('3', 'abc'),
 ('4', 'xyz'),
 ('5', 'xyz'),
 ('6', 'xyz')]
```